what is the webkit equivalent of input range ::-moz-range-progress?
That code makes the progress blue on firefox.
 input[type='range'].amplitude-song-slider::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 5px;
  background: var(--bs-blue);
}

It is not on chrome.


https://www.sitepoint.com/css-custom-range-slider/

it's unclear to me where the solution lies in the other question
